# Predictive model of time departure of an electrical vehicle

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

I'm actually working on a predictive model of time departure of an electrical vehicle with R. As data, I have a history of time departure of two years ago, which I'm looking to construct a predictive model with date (day) as input and the output of the model will be the time departure.
A step could be considered with one hour between two starts (example: `18h35`-->`18h00`)

1. I tried to see the problem as clustering one with (1 as "there is a departure" and 0 as "none" ) and apply randomForest model with (day and hour as input and 1 or 0 as output), but the model couldn't find the link between the output and input, and wathever the day or the hour, the model gives this result:  "1) root 13561 730 0 (0.9461 0.0538)*".
2. Other idea that came in mind is to work with time series, with arima or nnet but in vain I didn't get any result

Ps: you will find below, an image of how the data is given. But I have more than 1460 departure events corresponding to the 2 years of driving (2014,2015,2016).

[image: time departure]

Any idea for both methods ?

Comment: Arima won't work with the data as is above because you've got multiple departures for each time period. Are you trying to predict the average departure time (and if average what average  i.e. mean, median, mode)? or are you after predicting the number of departures?

Comment: Actually I m trying to predict the hour of departure with probability, for instance, as input "thursday", the model has to be able to tell me that in such day our client will leave at 5am (45%), 7pm(55%) and ...etc
wish that I explain it clearly 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the approach you mention I'm afraid the model won't be able to learn more than the average departure time across the whole  2years.

You obviously have to create more sophisticated calendar variables as model input. You might want to add:

- hour of the day (in numeric ou factor)
- type of day (weekday/saturday/sunday)
- national holidays/school holidays

And why not couple it with some climatic data, which, in my experience, have usually some influence:

- rain prediction
- outdoor temperature

Also you can add lagged variables:

- previous day usage (number of departures)
- usage of other vehicles

Having this set up, if you go with a linear model you have to test multiple interactions; but a machine learning model can yiels good results here (neural network of ensemble algorithm)

Anyway, I guess this sort of quesiton is more indicated for Cross Validated website